# Loop When True and False are Met

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code where TRUE and FALSE or always FALSE are always met. What I need to do is do different actions if one of them is TRUE or another logic if all are False

```js
let distance = [0.004996111561227907, 14.897649343418598, 5654.180955177425]

for(i=0; i< distance.length; i++){
 if(distance[i] < 0.05){
   $('#phrase').text('IM CLOSE!!')
  }else{
    $('#phrase').text('IM NOT CLOSE')
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="phrase">
  
</p>
```

Here's an example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/h5rbzLgn/

In here, one of the distances is `distance < 0.05` but the others are `distance > 0.05` so it always picks the logic for the false statement.

Is there a better way to do this where it can say if one of them is true, and if all of them are false?

Comment: Hi MCM. It's required when posting that your code is **in the question itself**, rather than forcing users to travel elsewhere to fully understand your question. For now, I've edited your question and added the external code to the body using a Stack Snippet. In the future, please use this approach instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to terminate the for loop when certain conditions are met.

```
let distance = [0.004996111561227907, 14.897649343418598, 5654.180955177425]

for(i=0; i< distance.length; i++){
  if(distance[i] < 0.05){
    $('#phrase').text('IM CLOSE!!')
    break;
  }else{
    $('#phrase').text('IM NOT CLOSE')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the JSFiddle, it is showing 'IM NOT CLOSE' because the last element is larger than 0.05

```js
let distance = [0.004996111561227907, 14.897649343418598, 5654.180955177425]

for (i = 0; i < distance.length; i++) {
  if (distance[i] < 0.05) {   // one of them are true
    console.log("I'M CLOSE!!");
    break;
  }
}
if (i === distance.length) {  // all of them are false
  console.log("I'M NOT CLOSE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your loop doesn't exit once it finds a `true` case. It evaluates every single element in the array and updates the text accordingly. As a result, the text will always correspond to the *last item in the array*. In this case, that item is NOT "close".

To exit the loop, use [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break):

```js
let distance = [0.004996111561227907, 14.897649343418598, 5654.180955177425]

for (i = 0; i < distance.length; i++) {
  if (distance[i] < 0.05) {
    $('#phrase').text('IM CLOSE!!')
    break;  //  <--------------------------- EXIT THE LOOP
  } else {
    $('#phrase').text('IM NOT CLOSE')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="phrase">

</p>
```

Although personally, I would use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). You can pass it a condition, and if *any* of the elements in your array satisfy the condition, it will stop and return `true`. Otherwise, it returns `false`.

```js
const CLOSE_DISTANCE = 0.05;

let distance = [0.004996111561227907, 14.897649343418598, 5654.180955177425];
let anyClose = distance.some(i => i < CLOSE_DISTANCE);
let message = anyClose ? "Close" : "Not Close";

$("#phrase").text(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="phrase"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

//use append

let distance = [
                                        0.004996111561227907,
                      14.897649343418598,
                      5654.180955177425]

```
for(let i in distance){
    if(distance[i] < 0.05){
    $('#phrase').append('IM CLOSE!!')
  }else{
    $('#phrase').append('IM NOT CLOSE')
  }
}
```